# fetching date from sqlite and display in UILabel view

Tags: ios, sqlite, date, uilabel

Hi in my Application I have date in my Local database in format of `dd-mm-yy`. Now I want to fetch the month related dates from my local database like for example jan means i want to fetch all jan dates from my local database. And i want to get the date dd separately month separately and year separately and store into string display in my UILabel. The fetching is not working properly please help me out.

In local database my date like when i print the array its showing like this  array11

```
"29-7-2014",
"15-8-2014",
"19-7-2014",
"20-7-2014",
"20-9-2014",
"18-9-2014",
"20-9-2014",
```

MY code database fetch code.

```
-(void)GETVALUE{

   [self openDB1];
   array11 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   array1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM cl"];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db1, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW) {

         char *field2 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
         NSString *field2Str =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];
         char *field1 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
         NSString *field1Str =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];

         NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",field1Str];
         NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",field2Str];

         [array11 addObject:str];
         [array1 addObject:str1];


        }

    }

 }
```

My compare code.

```
  mont = @"7";
  yr =@"2014";

  NSInteger mon = [mont intValue];
  NSInteger yea = [yr intValue];
  [self GETVALUE];
   NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

   NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

     NSArray *dobArray = array1;
     NSArray *messagesArray = array11;
     NSLog(@"%@",dobArray);
   for (NSString *dobStr in dobArray) {
       NSArray *components = [dobStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    if(components.count>3) {
        NSInteger aDay = [[components objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
        NSInteger aMonth = [[components objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
        NSInteger aYear = [[components objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

        if(aMonth == mon && aYear == yea) {

            [dateComponent setDay:aDay];
            [dateComponent setMonth:aMonth];
            [dateComponent setYear:aYear];

            UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
            [dp setDate:[gregCalendar dateFromComponents: dateComponent]];
            //inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dp];
           // NSLog(@"%@ss", inStr);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the above code but its not working its not checking please tell me how to achieve this one.

Thanks.

Comment: can u show your result of [array11 addObject:str];
         [array1 addObject:str1];

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have already given in the top please check it

Answer (score 0):

Change in below code replace with your for loop 
**Updated**

```
 for (int index = 0 ; index <dobArray.count ; index++) {
   NSArray *components = [dobStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
   if(components.count>3) {
         NSString *components = [dobArray objectAtIndex:index];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormet = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormet setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormet dateFromString:components];

        [dp setDate:date];
   }
 }
```

and now try . It'll work

Comment: The data contains dates with slashes as well - look above at the data dump.

Comment: @Joge please here where i have to check the condition of the month and year like i have checked in my code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very redundant and contains a lot of bizarre blossoms, such as

```
mont = @"7";
NSInteger mon = [mont intValue];
```

The first line is irrelevant, you can just write `7`. `intValue` returns an `int`, while `integerValue` returns an `NSInteger`.

or

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",field2Str];
```

where you could just use `field2Str`.

Your variable names are poorly chosen - which is why you are confused, as is every external reader of your code.

In `array1`, which for some reason is renamed `dobArray`  you store `str1`s from the database, which again are `field2Str`. Your comparison code is prone with potential errors, but it should work with the data you have posted. However, if you hit the date, you are allocating a date picker and doing nothing with it. It seems you should have a date picker initialised e.g. via storyboard and then setting the `date` of that picker.